# Generate column names as constants in a class at runtime

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, runtime, auto-generate

I have a database 'Sample' with a table 'User' with columns 'FirstName', 'LastName', 'Category'. I am using Entity Framework to access them by using 'ADO.Net Entity Data Model'. Now I am want to auto generate a class 'Fields' at runtime with some constants. Eg:

```
public Class Fields
{
    public const string firstName = "FirstName";
    public const string lastName = "LastName";
    public const string category = "Category";
}
```

I want to do this so that I can use them as my column name where ever needed. It will be easy to manage and use in the application. This is being used in my colleagues present project also but he don't have any clue like how it is being done as the project is quite big. Any other suggestion is always welcome for any other suggestion.

Comment: Why do you even need column names if you are using EF?

Comment: You couldn't make them const because that can't be changed at runtime. You could make them readonly though and set them in the constructor. Is the problem you are having with the fact they are constants or is there something else causing the problem? Setting fields in a class at runtime is pretty easy, you do it all the time, I'm sure. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be easily accomplished if you spent just a bit of time investigating "T4", which is built into Visual Studio. Here is a link to a blog post that has most of the information that you could piece together to do what you want pretty easily:

http://learneveryday.net/dot-net/code-generation-using-t4-templates/

Comment: That does look very cool, I'd not come across it before but the question did say that they need to be generated at runtime whereas that T4 stuff looks like it will get generated at compile time (or before). I should add as a note that this may in fact be what he wants and when he said "Runtime" that may not have been what was meant. :)

Comment: True, this would be compile time. I don't think you could do what you want at run-time, that is declaring consts at runtime, but why would you need to do that?

Comment: I'm not sure. You could obviously have readonly variables and it may be that this is dealing with varied datastructures (eg it might be pointing at something with a field "forename" rather than "firstname") and needing to therefore do some kind of mapping at runtime using datasource specific procedures to define the data structure... Its a bit of a silly situation but I can kind of see how it might work...

Comment: And even I am not sure why I want to do it on runtime after reading your answers. T4 looks cool and that do solves my problem. And I feel CodeSmith is also a good thing to consider but I am not sure of that. Thanks.

Comment: Codesmith is a good tool to. I've used both, codesmith is easier to use and imo less powerful; T4 is free, and more powerful, but a bit harder to get up to speed (but worth it)